# Julia: invalid assignment location when creating function to subset dataframe

Tags: dataframe, julia, subset

I am creating a function in Julia. It takes a dataframe (called window) and two strings (A and B) as inputs and subsets it using the variables given:

```
function calcs(window, A, B):
     fAB=size(window[(window[:ref].==A).&(window[:alt].==B),:])[1]
end
```

But I get the error:

```
syntax: invalid assignment location ":fAB"

Stacktrace:
 [1] include_string(::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:522
```

I have tried running the code outside of a function (having pre-assigned the variables `A="T"` and `B="C"` like so:

```
fAB=size(window[(window[:ref].==A).&(window[:alt].==B),:])[1]
```

and this runs fine. I am new to Julia but cannot find an answer to this question. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you come from Python world. In Julia you do not need to add `:` in function definition. This will go through fine:

```
function calcs(window, A, B)
     fAB=size(window[(window[:ref].==A).&(window[:alt].==B),:])[1]
end
```

When Julia encounters `:` in the first line of function definition it continues parsing the expression in the following line producing `:fAB` symbol.

EDIT: In Julia 0.7 this problem is detected by the parser. This is the result of copy-pasting your original code to REPL:

```
julia> function calcs(window, A, B):
            fAB=size(window[(window[:ref].==A).&(window[:alt].==B),:])[1]
ERROR: syntax: space not allowed after ":" used for quoting

julia> end
ERROR: syntax: unexpected "end"
```